# How to Email or attach the current image from image switcer using intent action send

Tags: android

I have loaded images from drawable folder into the image switcher. And I have placed a button in that activity. So if I click that button means, the current image in switcher should be mailed using intent's action_send.

Answer (score 1):

find which drawable is currently set and then

```
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.your file);
intent.setType("image/png");
```

to send multiple images

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
emailIntent.setType("image/png");

ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

uris.add(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.file1));
uris.add(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.file2));

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris));

startActivity(emailIntent);
```